# Interpolation error of InterpolatingPolynomial[]

Tags: numerics, interpolation, approximation

this is my first post so if I have any error while writing this, I'm sorry.

I had to do a polynomic interpolation for one of my lab experiments, and I need to get the error from it in order to continue. Any idea on how to do it?

This is the code:

```
f = {1.611 , 1.438 , 1.367 , 1.279 , 1.186 , 1.024 , 0.789 , 1.719 , 
   1.815 , 1.921 , 2.041 , 2.360 , 2.831};
i = {0.0453, 0.0412, 0.0383, 0.0342, 0.0288, 0.0216, 0.0142, 0.0433, 
   0.0400, 0.0367, 0.0321, 0.0237, 0.0173};
datos = Transpose[{f, i}]
interp = InterpolatingPolynomial[datos, x];
Expand[interp]
```

I supose every parameter from the interpolation will have it's own uncertainty, but what I don't know is if Mathematica is able to show them all to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: `5442.62 - 45353.6 x + 170957. x^2 - 385526. x^3 + 579400. x^4 - 
 611462. x^5 + 464716. x^6 - 256317. x^7 + 101841. x^8 - 
 28431.2 x^9 + 5294.38 x^10 - 590.532 x^11 + 29.8392 x^12` is wrong?

This is my result for your code.

Comment: Are you looking for an exact interpolation (as you did) of degree 12 ? Or are you looking for a polynomial approximation of your data p?

Comment: "I suppose every parameter from the interpolation will have it's own uncertainty" -- There two sources, the round-off error in computing `interp` and the experimental error in `f` and `i`.  I doubt a symbolic expression in terms of unknown individual errors in `f` and in `i` will be useful, but perhaps if the errors in `f` and `i` are each a known number or a known bound, then the uncertainty in the coefficients could be computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Total[(((interp /. x -> #)  & /@ f) - i)^2]
```

But the error is approximately zero. In abstract reality, this error is exactly 0, because you interpolate 13 values by the polynom of degree 12.